# Different values when use DB::raw() in second param on where()

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have next query in Laravel Eloquent:

```
$buildings = Building::select('buildings.*')->join(
    DB::raw('('.
        (
            IngameBuilding::select('buildings.building_id', 'buildings.level')
                          ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', '=', 'ingame_buildings.building_id')
                          ->toSql()
        ).
    ') as `added_buildings`'), 'added_buildings.building_id', '=', 'buildings.building_id')
    ->where('buildings.level', '>', 'added_buildings.level')
    ->get();
```

This query returns all allowed rows from base, but one row more. When I added `DB::raw()` in `where()` return values is valid.

Good-working code:

```
$buildings = Building::select('buildings.*')->join(
    DB::raw('('.
        (
          IngameBuilding::select('buildings.building_id', 'buildings.level')
                        ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', '=', 'ingame_buildings.building_id')
                        ->toSql()
        ).
    ') as `added_buildings`'), 'added_buildings.building_id', '=', 'buildings.building_id')
    ->where('buildings.level', '>', DB::raw('`added_buildings`.`level`'))
    ->get();
```

Why first code workig, hmm.. Wrong?

Comment: Could You please format the code a bit?
It's kinda hard to read one-liners.

Comment: Okay, give me a moment / Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of Laravel at all.
I've got only small experience with this framework but i'm almost sure that `where` function accepts only a 'constant' values to be checked against.

If you'll get an output of this query using `toSQL` method on the query object you will see that eloquent will convert it as something like:

```
(...) where buildings.level > 'added_buildings.level'
```

so the condition checks if the `buildings.level` (whatever the type is)
is greater than the given string and not the column value.

Using the `DB::raw` you're getting the proper sql as the eloquent won't parse/convert it.

You would need to use `whereRaw` method I suppose. 
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#introduction

Comment: Yeah, I think `where()` is wrong working where SQL code is a second param. Thank you